# How to split in blocks a file and count the intermediate lines

Tags: perl

I have a file like this:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=14430001 step=1
144300010.000
0.002
0.030
0.990
0.000
0.000
0.000
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=14430001 step=1
0.000
0.000
0.000
```

and I would like to take the number of the start from every line that it starts with fixedStep and put a counter in every of the other lines.
eg.

```
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=14430001 step=1
14430001   0.000
14430002   0.002
14430003   0.030
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=16730005 step=1
16730005   0.990
16730006   0.000
.........
```

I wrote this code but doesn't work.

```
open my $scores_info, $scores_file or die "Could not open $scores_file: $!";
while( my $sline = <$scores_info>)  {

    if ($sline=~ m/fixedStep/) {
        my @data = split(' ', $sline);
        my @begin = split('=', $data[2]);
        my $start = $begin[1];
        print "$start\n";
        my $nextline = <$scores_info>;
        $start++;
        print $start . "\t" .  $nextline;
    }
```

An finally to print it in a new file.
Could you help me please??
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encounter a line with "fixedStep", set `$count` and print the line. Otherwise, print and increment `$count`:

```
my $count = 0;
while( my $sline = <$scores_info>)  {

    if ($sline=~ m/fixedStep/) {
        my @data = split(' ', $sline);
        my @begin = split('=', $data[2]);
        $count = $begin[1];
        print $sline;
    } else {
        print $count++ . "\t" . $sline;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=14430001 step=1
14430001    144300010.000
14430002    0.002
14430003    0.030
14430004    0.990
14430005    0.000
14430006    0.000
14430007    0.000
fixedStep chrom=chr22 start=16730005 step=1
16730005    0.990
16730006    0.000
16730007    0.000
```